# How to zip CSV files through stored function in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, zip, stored-functions

I am generating a few CSV files using COPY statements from postgres in a stored function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."create_csv" () RETURNS INT AS
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('COPY (SELECT * FROM test) TO %L DELIMITER '','' CSV HEADER', '/tmp/test.csv');
    EXECUTE format('COPY (SELECT * FROM test2) TO %L DELIMITER '','' CSV HEADER', '/tmp/test2.csv');
RETURN 0;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER
```

This function is called from a parent one, after the execution of that I want to zip the generated CSV files into a zip file, how can I accomplish this using stored functions in the data base? Is there a way to do so using plpgsql? Or should i use plpythonu language?
Postgres version 9.6.
Thanks!

Comment: You can send the output of the copy command to a program on the server. Something like `copy .. to program 'gzip ...'`. There is an example in the manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.10

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately that option does not resolve my issue. What I want to do is, generate a variable number of CSV files using several COPY statements and after that (once all CSV files are generated), zip all of them into a single xx.zip file. Is that possible using TO program? is there any other option? Can someone provide an example?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@a_horse_with_no_name gave you an alert about what you should do use copy ... PROGRAM, just add the code at the end of your function, in this case in tar format:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."create_csv" () RETURNS INT AS
$$
BEGIN
 EXECUTE format('COPY (SELECT * FROM test) TO %L DELIMITER '','' CSV HEADER', '/tmp/test.csv');
 EXECUTE format('COPY (SELECT * FROM test2) TO %L DELIMITER '','' CSV HEADER', '/tmp/test2.csv');
 --add copy commando with PROGRAM
 COPY (SELECT 1) TO PROGRAM 'tar cvf /tmp/mytarfile.tar --remove-files /tmp/*.csv';
RETURN 0;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER
```

Comment: Thanks a lot yo both (a_horse_with_no_name and Anthony Sotolongo) that Copy PROGRAM solve my case! :)